# Pandas Multi-Index EWMA: Comparing same minute over multiple days

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I am trying to plug a data set into Pandas and am doing something a bit unique with the approach.

I have a data set that looks like the following:

```
Date, Time, Venue, Volume, SummedVolume
2015-09-14, 09:30, NYSE, 1000, 10000
2015-09-14, 09:31, NYSE, 1100, 10100
```

However, I have this data sliced by minute per date. I have files going back a number of days, so I call a certain number of them and concat them into my DataFrame, typically using the last 20 days.

What I would like to do is use pandas ewma to do an ewma on the exact same minute of the day, across those 20 days, by Venue. So what the result would be, is comparing the 09:30 minute across the last 20 days for NYSE, using an alpha of 0.5 (which I think would be span=20 in this case). Obviously, sort the data so that the oldest data is at the back and newest data is at the front is critical, so I am doing that as well, the data can't be in a random order.

Right now I am able to get pandas to do simple math (means, etc) on this data set using groupby on Time and Venue (shown below). However, when I try to do an ewma on this, I get errors about not being able to do an ewma on a non-unique data set - which is reasonable. But adding the Date into the MultiIndex kind of wrecks being able to compare the same exact minute to that minute on other dates.

Can anyone think of a solution here?

```
frame = pd.DataFrame()
concat = []

for fn in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(fn, index_col=None, header=0)
    concat.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(concat)

df = pd.DataFrame(frame)

if conf == "VenueStats":
    grouped = df.groupby(['time','Venue'], sort=True)
elif conf == "SymbolStats":
    grouped = df.groupby(['time','Symbol'], sort=True)

stats = grouped.mean().astype(int)

stats.to_csv('out.csv')
```

#### Initial output from df.head() before the mean (I changed the Venue names and values to 0 since this is sensitive information):

```
         Date   Time         Venue  Volume  SummedVolume
0  2015-09-14  17:00          NYSE       0             0
1  2015-09-14  17:00          ARCA       0             0
2  2015-09-14  17:00          AMEX       0             0
3  2015-09-14  17:00        NASDAQ       0             0
4  2015-09-14  17:00          BATS       0             0
```

#### Output from stats.head() after the mean:

```
                     Volume  SummedVolume
Time  Venue
00:00 NYSE              0               0
      ARCA              0               0
      AMEX              0               0
      NASDAQ            0               0
      BATS              0               0
```

Here is what is different from doing a mean (above) to when I try to do the ewma:

```
for fn in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(fn, index_col=[0,1,2], header=0) #0=Date,1=Time,2=Venue
    concat.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(concat)

df = pd.DataFrame(frame, columns=['Volume','SummedVolume'])

if conf == "VenueStats":
    stats = df.groupby(df.index).apply(lambda x: pd.ewma(x,span=20))
elif conf == "SymbolStats":
    stats = df.groupby(df.index).apply(lambda x: pd.ewma(x,span=20))
```

Here is the df.head() from the ewma version and the stats.head() from the ewma version (they look the same):

```
                           Volume  SummedVolume
Date       Time  Venue
2015-09-14 17:00 NYSE           0        0
                 ARCA           0        0
                 AMEX           0        0
                 NASDAQ         0        0
                 BATS           0        0

                           Volume  SummedVolume
Date       Time  Venue
2015-09-14 17:00 NYSE           0        0
                 ARCA           0        0
                 AMEX           0        0
                 NASDAQ         0        0
                 BATS           0        0
```

Comment: Can you please provide the results of `df.head()` and `stats.head()`?

Comment: For the mean() or ewma() version?

Comment: for the ewma version please.

Comment: I've reworked my solution to incorporate the format.  It should work for volume.  If so, I'll extend it to do both volume and streamV.

Comment: Here is the feedback I get from plugging that in: AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'unstack' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Comment: Oops. Try the amended version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to pivot your data so that dates are down one axis and time the other.

It is difficult to work on this problem without some reproduceable data, but the solution would be something like this:

```
df2 = (df.reset_index()
       .groupby(['tradeDate', 'time', 'exchange'])
       .first()  # Given that the data is unique by selected grouping
       .unstack(['exchange', 'time'])
pd.ewma(df2, span=20)
```